Applicability of averaging to LLC resonant converter
I have read conflicting reports on the applicability of the averaging technique to LLC resonant converters:
On one hand on Microchip’s App Note 1477 “Digital Compensator Design for LLC Resonant Converter“ it says on the first page that "For LLC converter modeling, the method of  averaging cannot be used because some state variables do not have a DC operating point"
On the other hand on page 418 of Vorperian’s book “Fast Analytical Techniques for Electrical and Electronic Circuits“ it says that “the PWM switch is applicable to all converters that are switched between two states”, and on page 402 of the same book it is stated that the PWM switch can be represented by the following average equations:
$$
i_a = d i_c \\
v_{cp} = d v_{ap}
$$
and the following average equivalent circuit model:

So in the case of this half-bridge LLC converter:

the converter is switched between two states (state 1: high-side on, low side off, state 2:  high-side off, low side on), therefore one should be able to analyse this converter using an averaged circuit model like this:

But this contradicts the assertion on Microchip’s App Note. So which one is correct?

Neither is correct if you don't properly take into account leakage inductance effects on both secondary and primary sides. Or, put another way, you appear to be lumping the transformer leakage into the series component on the primary side and, this can easily deceive you on the transformer core saturation levels.

The microchip document appears to have the rectifying MOSFETs connected incorrectly on the secondary side so I would have doubts about its validity.

Thanks @Andyaka for your reply, the Microchip app note might be incorrect on that but I have been unable to find an average model for an LLC elsewhere as well, so it seems it's not related to a misunderstanding in one company alone
